# Read file of objects and write it back to a new one a single character at a time

Tags: java, io, ascii, nio

How to read an entire record from a txt file, get each field separately and convert each field into a separate character stream. Then write the character streams of individual characters (in a loop) to a plain ASCII output text file.

I have my class definition, I just cannot seem to write the output file properly which has to be one individual plain ascii text character at a time. I just need a little help. Here is what I have so far:

----- This is my first question guys. Sorry if it isn't formatted well :( I'm trying to covert a file of objects to a plain **ASCII character** text file which i called **"yankees.txt"** I read it in with the `ObjectInputStream` then I'm supposed to get each field separately and convert each field into a seperate character stream, and write the characters one character at a time from each field to my **"yankees.txt"**

```
public class yankeesfilemain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EOFException {
        ObjectInputStream is;
        OutputStream os;

        yankees y;
        int i, j, k;
        String name, pos;
        int number;
        File fout;
        try {
            is = new ObjectInputStream(new
                FileInputStream("yankees.yanks"));
            y = (yankees)is.readObject();

            fout = new File("yankees.txt");
            os = new FileOutputStream(fout);

            while (y != null) {
                name = y.getname();
                pos = y.getpos();
                number = y.getnum();
                for (i = 0; i < .length(); i++) {}
                for (j = 0; j < .length(); j++) {
                    pos = y.getpos();   
                }
                for (k = 0; k < .length(); k++) {
                    number = y.getnum();
                }

                break;
            }
            os.close();
            is.close();
        } catch(EOFException eof) {
            eof.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles for your questions.

Comment: What language are you using Java or JavaScript - they are two completely different languages.

Comment: @jeff Looks like Java to me...but what do I know ;)

Comment: So, you seem to want to read an `Object` from a file and then write each of it's fields out to a separate file(s)....?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, then we're in deep trouble because you probably know more than me :-)

Comment: @jeff I wouldn't say that, I just have field of experience ;)

Comment: This is my first question guys. Sorry if it isn't formatted well :( I'm trying to covert a file of objects to a plain ASCII character text file which i called "yankees.txt" I read it in with the ObjectInputStream then I'm supposed to get each field separately and convert each field into a seperate character stream, and write the characters one character at a time from each field to my "yankees.txt"

Comment: Can anyone help me :( ? ugh

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to read objects from a file and write each of its fields one ASCII character at a time to ONE file. Can you help :-( ?

Comment: anyone? I really need some help. I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\11.txt");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\12.txt", true);

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int byteRead = in.read(buffer);
            if (byteRead == -1)
                break;
            out.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
        }
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.err.println(args[0] + " is not a URL Java understands.");
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }

    }

}
```